# IIS Just in Time Popup

Tags: iis, asp-classic

We had a classic ASP application that had to be migrated to a new Windows Server (Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter).  IIS was already setup and we migrated the files configured the URL and DNS, as well as setting up the classic ASP components for IIS.  The web application initially opens okay but the error below pops up on the server continually.

[image]

We checked the relevant site was configured to run 32bit and we ensured that in the sites "Debugging properties" the "Enable Server-side Debugging" was set to false.  Also, all those testing the site we ensured in Internet Options >> Advanced the two values of "Disable script debugging" were checked.  But this did not resolve the error. I believe we have all the necessary components setup in the server roles

[image]

I then followed this URL and deleted certain registry entries and restarted the server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015

This seemed to take away the above error but then the relevant application pool continually stops.  I checked the application logs and at each time the application pool stops there is an error stating below

[image]

Since creating this ticket I installed DebugDiag 2 and set up a rule for IIS "Crashing".  Ran the application until the relevant IIS Application Pool stopped and examined the Dump files created by the rule.  All of them appear to have one error concerning "VCRUNTIME140.dll".  See image below.

[image]

I found that this was a common issue and related to Visual C++ Redistributable 2015.  I looked at installed programs and there was versions 2010, 2013 and 2017 installed.  Microsoft state that after version 2013 subsequent versions incorporate the last.  So I installed the latest version of Visual C++ Redistributable and restarted the server.  This made no difference.  So I uninstalled the latest version and installed version 2015 and restarted but again the application pool still stops after several actions on the web application.

Does anyone know how do I resolve this please?

Comment: IIS might be trying to write to a file for which it doesn't have permission. Is there any more information available under the details tab?

Comment: @Adam - not really.  Pretty much the same as is in the General tab.  Just the w3wp.exe. the kernellbase.dll, a few codes and the two paths to the w3wp and kernelbase

Comment: Which are the components that are installed? Some older 32bit components work, and some dont, and throw this error. A list of the components installed could give an indication.

Comment: @Sourcery Thanks for feedback.  I have added an image to show the server roles and components for the web server element.  I think all the necessary ones are present

Comment: Hello again, sorry for late reply... You are only showing a list of the roles and components that comes with Windows. Ususally it is 3rd part components that fail. Do you know which 3rd party components might be used?

Comment: @Sourcery Thanks again for feedback.  No need to apologise. So, 3rd party components - do you mean 3rd party components for the browser, IIS or the application?

Comment: So this is for the IIS/application. Ususally in older ASP pages there were compnents installed on the server that did things that are built in to asp.net and more recent iis. Examples are jmail, aspimage, abcupload, and countless more ofcourse, do you know if you have any of these com-components installed.

Comment: @Sourcery Thanks again.  I will have a look but it is the Easter holiday here and they are locking up the building soon.  It will be a few days before I update again

Comment: @Sourcery Back again.  I investigated and the only third party component used to provide all the applications functionality is a component called JustGage found at https://justgage.com/

Comment: Looks like it is only javascript based and shouldnt interfere with the IIS. Ok, moving along... If you have only one person visiting the site, can you pinpoint the exact page that is visited when this error is created?

Comment: @Sourcery I had a look at when the application pool stops when several users use the application.  Doesn't seem to be any indicators jumping out.  Only consistent pattern is after a user processes 5 or 6 actions on the application the the application pool stops.  Very strange!!!

Comment: @Sourcery I installed Microsoft DebugDiag 2 and setup a rule for IIS Crashing.  All the dump files give the same error and I amended question above to show this.

Comment: Make sure that Visual C++ 2015 is correctly installed seems to be related to this file. Could you check IF it is installed if it is 32 or 64 bit version? Article here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/vcruntime140dll/b1a15b0e-e389-41a3-bc49-f4fc85bac575

Comment: @Sourcery Thanks again.  yes, I found some similar clues on Google that it was to do with Visual C++ Redistributable 2015.  I have amended the question above to explain what I have tried but the Application Pool is still stopping.  Struggling for a solution now!!!